# How to register numeric value as nested property in react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a property called totals which should contain several nested object as properties.

Here is my desired form structure:

```
{
  totals: {
      0: {
        value: 0,
      },
    },
 };
```

However react-hook-form docs states that setting a number as a nested property creates the value at the indicated index so this code

```
setValue(`totals.2`, {
  value: 0,
});
```

is giving me this undesired outcome:

```
{
  totals: [, , {
        value: 0,
      }]
 };
```

[image]

Any ideas how on how to set numeric nested properties?

Comment: Doesn’t look like it can be done purely the way you want in react hook form https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/9409#discussioncomment-4201421. You’ll have to transform your values  to an array first

Comment: To an array if you have default values and are setting them on form load, from an array if you are handling validation using a schema  that doesn’t support an array or on submit to an API. Either way, the structure inside the form will always be an array when your keys are numeric

Comment: This should almost certainly be done by transforming before/after (depending on the needs) and just letting react hook form behave “normally” instead of trying to hack RHF as the answer below suggests. Can you elaborate on why you “need” the values totals to be a numerically indexed object instead of an array? Your specific requirements will result in an answer that gives you the best approach to solve your problem

Comment: I have a multi react select where I select a couple of user then after selecting these couple of users I create a table where I can register and edit fields for each user. I need the numeric property because the user id are integers and dont' want to use array fields because then if the index is 190 for example it will create an array of nulls and the last index as my item. Also, using the db id as my property key is more reliable when adding/removing users and registering/unregistering their values instead of using the index.

Comment: Is it possible to have a mini transformation step so that the field name in the form is actually like `id-{int}`. When loading values into the form, you’d have to prefix the numeric key with id- and on the way out of the form (submission to the server) you’d just strip id- prefix

Comment: yes this is what I am actually doing, just thought that it is not very intuitive to have to add the prefix when setting and retrieving the items and also remove it while submitting.

Comment: You're doing it as right as you can. RHF documentation is very good and clear, if it's not documented it's not supported. I've gone through the pains before of base64 encoding every "key" in my data source so as not to run into problems in RHF (the keys were dynamic and had odd characters in addition to periods and numbers). encoded all the keys on the way into the form and decoded all the field names on the way out. What you're doing is fine

Answer (score 1):

This is not in the docs, but there is a way to get around this limitation.

The first time you `register()` a field with sub-fields the library will check if that sub-field is a number or text.
If it is a number it will create an array, otherwise it will  create an object.
For every subsequent `register()` it will simply add sub-fields on that object or array without checking if the sub-field is a number or not.

---

Here's a demonstration of how we can use this:

```js
// first register a dummy text field
// this will cause field `foo` to be an object with one sub-field `bar`
register('foo.bar');

// then register our numeric sub-fields
register('foo.1');
register('foo.2.value');

// then get rid of the dummy sub-field `bar`
unregister('foo.bar');

// now we can set the value of those numeric fields
// and you don't have to worry about it turning into an array
setValue('foo.1', 'lorem');
setValue('foo.2.value', 'ipsum');

// here's what we get at the end
console.log(getValues());
const result = {
    "foo": {
        "1": "lorem",
        "2": {
            "value": "ipsum"
        }
    }
}
```

---

With this we can construct this helper function:

```js
const getRegisterOnObject = (register, unregister) => (path, options) =>
{
    const tempPath = path.replace(/(\d+)/g, '__$1');
    if (tempPath !== path) // if there are numbers in the path we need a dummy field
    {
        register(tempPath);
        const res = register(path, options);
        unregister(tempPath);
        return res;
    }
    else // if there are no numbers then we should not create a dummy field
    {
        return register(path, options);
    }
};
```

Every time you want to register a field it will temporarily create a dummy field and remove it as soon as it is not needed.
The dummy field will be th like this: `foo.__2` or `foo.__2.value` etc...

We can then use it in our components to extend the basic `register()` function:

```js
// get the modified `register()` function
const registerOnObject = getRegisterOnObject(register, unregister);

// proceed to register fields like you usually would
registerOnObject('foo.2');

// if you are only registering in one place then it is simpler to write it in one line
getRegisterOnObject(register, unregister)('foo.2');
```

---

In the previous version of the answer I suggested using hooks to create dummy fields, but I believe the above is more practical.

The old answer:

You'll want to put this just below your call to `useForm()`

```js
// first we register() our dummy field in useMemo()
// because useMemo() is called right away
useMemo(() => {register('foo.bar')}, []);
// then we unregister() it inside useEffect()
// because useEffect() is called after our component is rendered
useEffect(() => {unregister('foo.bar')}, []);
```

This way you'll have `foo.bar` during the first render and the lib will put numeric fields under the `foo` object.

If you have more than one such field you'll have to initialize all of them, like this:

```js
useMemo(() => {register('fooA.bar');register('fooB.bar')}, []);
useEffect(() => {unregister('fooA.bar');unregister('fooB.bar')}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I find this approach a a bit too hacky) Would prefer to just add the prefix instead and make it a string property if there is no way to use numeric properties.

Comment: @CharlesSemaan Now that you mention adding prefixes I got an idea of adding temporary prefixes with a helper function, which eliminates the need for all those hooks. This new way feels much less like a hack

Comment: Done but I won't accept this answer but it's just a way around the problem) This feature Iis currently not supported in RHF as I understand.

Comment: I doubt it will be supported unless they decide to allow us to pass an array of strings & numbers, instead of a single string for the whole path